# nothing happens when executing java process command

Tags: java, process

Why can't I run this:

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/c", "\"C:\\Program Files\\Gdal\\bin\\gdal\\apps\\ogr2ogr.exe\" -f \"" + "ESRI Shapefile" + "\" \"" + "C:\\Temp\\world.shp" +"\" PG:\"host=" + MainDialog.host + " user=" + MainDialog.dbUser + " password=" + MainDialog.dbPassword + " dbname=" + MainDialog.dataBase + "\" \"" + layerName + "\" -dim " + coordformat});
```

Which results in command:

```
"C:\Program Files\Gdal\bin\gdal\apps\ogr2ogr.exe" -f "ESRI Shapefile" "C:\Temp\world.shp" PG:"host=127.0.0.1 user=puser password=pwd dbname=db1" "world" -dim XY
```

This command can be executed in a Windows cmd-terminal without any problems...
but when running the java process nothing happens, no error codes.

Comment: What do you mean "nothing happens"? What should happen?

Comment: Does this app write a lot of messages when run in Windows cmd-terminal ?

Comment: it writes no messages when ok, as in this case with executing in a terminal window

Comment: the process should exporta shape filefrom a database. When stepping forward in debug mode it seems ok but the process seems not to be executing. There is no shapefile written on disk. But when running the command in a cmd terminal it work

Answer (score 0):

Runtime.exec is obsolete.  Use [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) instead.  This will not only give your process more flexibility, it will also remove the need for all those extra quotation marks.

Many processes hang if they fill up their output or error buffer and no other process consumes it.

If you don’t care about the output of the process, just use [inheritIO()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO()) to make sure none of it is blocked:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
    "C:\\Program Files\\Gdal\\bin\\gdal\\apps\\ogr2ogr.exe",
    "-f", "ESRI Shapefile",
    "C:\\Temp\\world.shp",
    "PG:host=" + MainDialog.host,
    "user=" + MainDialog.dbUser,
    "password=" + MainDialog.dbPassword,
    "dbname=" + MainDialog.dataBase,
    layerName, "-dim", coordformat);

builder.inheritIO();

process = builder.start();
```

Notice that none of the arguments need to be quoted, and in fact must not be quoted.

If you do care about the output of the process, you can manually do some of the steps which inheritIO() does:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
    "C:\\Program Files\\Gdal\\bin\\gdal\\apps\\ogr2ogr.exe",
    "-f", "ESRI Shapefile",
    "C:\\Temp\\world.shp",
    "PG:host=" + MainDialog.host,
    "user=" + MainDialog.dbUser,
    "password=" + MainDialog.dbPassword,
    "dbname=" + MainDialog.dataBase,
    layerName, "-dim", coordformat);

builder.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
builder.redirectInput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);

process = builder.start();

try (InputStream processOutput = process.getInputStream()) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: No improvement, same result as before. Does java process read the environment variables ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help everyone!

When using

"ogr2ogr.exe"

instead of
"C:\Program Files\Gdal\bin\gdal\apps\ogr2ogr.exe"

in the progressBuilder, it works...

It uses system path which is set to C:\Program Files\Gdal\bin\gdal\apps
The strange thing is that it worked with the old version of ogr2ogr.exe, placed in C:\Program Files\OSGeo4W64\bin.

I don't understand....